# Split string by multiple characters in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, split, delphi-7, tstringlist

I want to know how to split a string with multiple characters in Deplhi 7.
I know how to split a string with one character:

```
strlst := TStringList.Create;
strlst.Delimiter := '^';
strlst.DelimitedText := receivedtext;
```

And this is how I can split a string in Delphi XE7 with multiple characters.

```
strlst := tstringlist.create;
strlst.LineBreak := '<>';
strlst.Text := receivedtext;
```

But Delphi 7 doesn't have the `LineBreak` method.
Is there another way to split a string by multiple characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the source code for XE7 so you can simply use the same method as it does in Delphi 7. It might look like this:

```
procedure SetStringsText(Strings: TStrings; const Text, LineBreak: string);
var
  P, Start, LB: PChar;
  S: string;
  LineBreakLen: Integer;
begin
  Strings.BeginUpdate;
  try
    Strings.Clear;
    LineBreakLen := Length(LineBreak);
    P := PChar(Text);
    while P^ <> #0 do
    begin
      Start := P;
      LB := AnsiStrPos(P, PChar(LineBreak));
      while (P^ <> #0) and (P <> LB) do Inc(P);
      SetString(S, Start, P - Start);
      Strings.Add(S);
      if P = LB then
        Inc(P, LineBreakLen);
    end;
  finally
    Strings.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```